# Multivariate Gaussian transformation that preserves dependencies?

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, data-transformation

I have a dataset consisting of 2 multidimensional (multi-column) arrays $X$ and $Y$. All columns in $X$ and $Y$ are drawn from continuous distribution and are correlated between each other (the distribution itself is unknown but the closest fits are Gamma and lognormal distributions). Further, $X$ and $Y$ are also correlated between each other.

The overall problem that I am facing is to measure the mutual information between $X$ and $Y$. For the purpose I have been using mutual information numerical estimators, however, as the number of dimension in $X$ and $Y$ increases these estimators and practically useless. So, my idea is to transform $X$ and $Y$ to Gaussian which will make the problem more tractable and hopefully allow me to find an analytical solution, i.e., remove the need of the numerical estimators.

The approach I am trying is to transform the two arrays $X$ and $Y$ to multivariate Gaussians and preserve their correlation. Methods I have tried so far:

1. **Quantile transform**: This transform is applied on each column independently. So, when I input $X$ (or $Y$) it outputs an array $X_Q$ (or $Y_Q$), where each column is a Gaussian variable but the columns are not jointly Gaussian and therefore $X_Q$ ($Y_Q$) itself is not Gaussian, too. This transform, however, preserves the correlation, i.e., $corr(X,Y)=corr(X_Q,Y_Q)$.
2. **Rotation-based iterative Gaussianization**: This transform is applied on all dimensions simultaneously, so when I input $X$ (or $Y$) it outputs an multivariate Gaussian array $X_R$ (or $Y_R$), however, the correlation is no longer preserved, i.e., $corr(X,Y)\neq corr(X_R,Y_R)$.

Any suggestions on a transform that could produce multivariate Gaussian while still preserving the dependencies? Or any suggestions on how to estimate the mutual information between $X$ and $Y$ assuming that their marginal distributions are known but their joint PDF is not.

Comment: If you define the correlation to be rank-correlation, then the quantile based approach (i.e. copulas) works just fine

Comment: Such a transformation is often mathematically impossible.  Thus, you would likely get more useful answers by giving more specific information about the problem you actually face.  At a minimum, shall we presume $X$ and $Y$ have continuous distributions and you are asking about transforming these *random variables* rather than transforming the *data?*  And what exactly do you mean by "multidimensional variables" and how might they be related to "features" and "dimensions"?

Comment: Although your problem can be solved, it takes some work--a numerical search--which prompts me to wonder what you hope this transformation will accomplish.

Comment: The problem boils down to the fact that I want to measure mutual information (MI) between $X$ and $Y$. I tried some numerical estimators, however, as the dimensions go up these estimators do not work anymore. I want to transform the arrays to Gaussian as things become much easier then (but of course I do not want to lose MI on the way). Can you please tell me a bit more on how the problem can be solved?

Comment: I wonder what form of MI would survive this kind of transformation.  It sounds like you might be proposing an invalid solution to a different problem.  Why not back up a bit and describe the problem you *actually* face?

Comment: Hi @whuber, thanks for suggesting that. I have now edited the question accordingly.